# Error during compilling on python/fortran of Siesta libraries (Error: Line truncated)

Tags: python, ubuntu, compiler-errors, fortran, siesta

I'm currently trying to install libraries for Siesta modelling soft. I have zero programming expirience and tried work with manuals and guides. I work with Ubuntu on Windows 10. I install all uppdates and soft that was asked (not 100% sure though) During programm compiling I got error that can't be solved with software update (part of compiler text below). All I have found that this error probably connected with number of symbols in line but I don't know how th change compiler settings. Would appreciate any help in solution of this problem. Libraries was taken here: https://gitlab.com/ElectronicStructureLibrary/esl-bundle

```
make -j 9 Making all in src make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src' Making all in wxml make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/wxml' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/wxml' Making all in cml make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/cml' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/cml' Making all in sax make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/sax' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/sax' Making all in xpath make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/xpath' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/xpath' Making all in dom make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/dom' make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'. make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/dom' Making all in . make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src' /bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=compile gfortran  -g -O2 -c -o xmlf90_info.lo xmlf90_info.f90 libtool: compile:  gfortran -g -O2 -c xmlf90_info.f90  -fPIC -o .libs/xmlf90_info.o libtool: compile:  gfortran -g -O2 -c xmlf90_info.f90 -o xmlf90_info.o >/dev/null 2>&1 /bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran  -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0 -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib  -o libxmlf90.la -rpath /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib xmlf90_info.lo cml/libxmlf90_cml.la dom/libxmlf90_dom.la sax/libxmlf90_sax.la wxml/libxmlf90_wxml.la xpath/libxmlf90_xpath.la libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libxmlf90.a .libs/libxmlf90.la .libs/libxmlf90.lai .libs/libxmlf90.so .libs/libxmlf90.so.0 .libs/libxmlf90.so.0.0.0 libtool: link: gfortran -shared  -fPIC  .libs/xmlf90_info.o  -Wl,--whole-archive cml/.libs/libxmlf90_cml.a dom/.libs/libxmlf90_dom.a sax/.libs/libxmlf90_sax.a wxml/.libs/libxmlf90_wxml.a xpath/.libs/libxmlf90_xpath.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libxmlf90.so.0 -o .libs/libxmlf90.so.0.0.0 libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libxmlf90.so.0" && ln -s "libxmlf90.so.0.0.0" "libxmlf90.so.0") libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libxmlf90.so" && ln -s "libxmlf90.so.0.0.0" "libxmlf90.so") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/cml/.libs/libxmlf90_cml.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/dom/.libs/libxmlf90_dom.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/sax/.libs/libxmlf90_sax.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/wxml/.libs/libxmlf90_wxml.a") libtool: link: (cd .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_xpath.a && ar x "/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src/xpath/.libs/libxmlf90_xpath.a") libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libxmlf90.a  xmlf90_info.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a/m_wcml.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a/m_wstml.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_cml.a/xmlf90_cml.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_attribute.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_debug.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_document.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_element.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_error.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_namednodemap.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_node.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_nodelist.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_parse.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_strings.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_types.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/m_dom_utils.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_dom.a/xmlf90_dom.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_buffer.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_charset.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_converters.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_debug.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_dictionary.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_elstack.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_entities.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_fsm.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_sax_reader.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_xml_error.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/m_xml_parser.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_sax.a/xmlf90_sax.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_array_str.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_buffer.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_core.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_dictionary.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_elstack.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_error.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_escape.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_overloads.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/m_wxml_text.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_wxml.a/xmlf90_wxml.o  .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_xpath.a/m_xpath_api.o .libs/libxmlf90.lax/libxmlf90_xpath.a/xmlf90_xpath.o ar: u' modifier ignored since D' is the default (see U')
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libxmlf90.a
libtool: link: rm -fr .libs/libxmlf90.lax
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libxmlf90.la" && ln -s "../libxmlf90.la" "libxmlf90.la" )
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/src'
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc'
Making all in Examples
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples'
Making all in cml
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/cml'
/bin/bash ../../../libtool  --tag=FC   --mode=link gfortran -I../../../src/cml -I../../../src/wxml -g -O2  -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib  -o example example.o ../../../src/libxmlf90.la
libtool: link: gfortran -I../../../src/cml -I../../../src/wxml -g -O2 -o .libs/example example.o  -L/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib ../../../src/.libs/libxmlf90.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/install/lib
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/cml'
Making all in dom
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/dom'
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o data.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/data.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o features.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/features.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o pseudo.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o pseudo_dom.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo_dom.F90
gfortran -DPACKAGE_NAME="XMLF90" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME="xmlf90" -DPACKAGE_VERSION="1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_STRING="XMLF90\ 1.5.4" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT="https://bugs.launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE_URL="https://launchpad.net/xmlf90\" -DPACKAGE="xmlf90" -DVERSION="1.5.4" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=".libs/" -I. -I/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -DDOM_DATA_DIR="/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/"  -I../../../src/dom -I../../../src/sax -g -O2 -c -o text.o /mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/text.F90
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/features.F90:9:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"test.xml" ) !! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/features.F90:9:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"test.xml" ) !! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo.F90:27:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'features.o' failed
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo.F90:27:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
make[3]: *** [features.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/data.F90:9:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml",verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/data.F90:9:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml",verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/text.F90:13:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"big-file.xml")!! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo_dom.F90:32:132:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/text.F90:13:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"big-file.xml")!! , verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/checkouts/xmlf90-1.5.4/doc/Examples/dom/pseudo_dom.F90:32:123:
myDoc => parsefile(DOM_DATA_DIR//"pseudo.xml")  !  ,verbose=.true.)
1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'data.o' failed
make[3]: *** [data.o] Error 1
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'pseudo.o' failed
make[3]: *** [pseudo.o] Error 1
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'text.o' failed
make[3]: *** [text.o] Error 1
Makefile:679: recipe for target 'pseudo_dom.o' failed
make[3]: *** [pseudo_dom.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples/dom'
Makefile:478: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc/Examples'
Makefile:385: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/siesta-4.1-b4/esl-bundle-master/esl-bundle-master/my_build_dir/xmlf90/doc'
Makefile:528: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
...ending phase build module xmlf90  stderr: ########## Error running make -j 9
*** Error during phase build of xmlf90: ########## Error running make -j 9 *** [8/13]
```

Comment: I'll just say python and Fortran are completely different generations. If you say you have little experience it might be better focusing on one language (if you have that option). On top of that you are adding `siesta` (javascript or IOS?)...When someone is learning to program they usually focus on one language first until they get a grasp for the fundamentals...And additionally you are installing libraries in linux? Go for something easy to install, if you can keep things simple at the start, one environment, one language until you get the hang of it. Best of luck.

Comment: If you're new to building software, then it would be advisable to not use the `-j` option for `make` as messages get interleaved.

Comment: Ask the author of the software if your compiler version is supported and whether he compiler options are correct. I do not think you can do much more without learning programming and examining the code. And we cannot do that for you.